# Duplicated event binding with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, binding

I'm having a problem with duplicated event binding while using jQuery.

I have a menu which items loads portions of HTML, JavaScript and CSS code via Ajax in a container. Each portion of code binds events to elements shown within. When a menu element is clicked twice then the event binding is done again, so events are fired several times when called.

I solved this with:

```
$([el1, el2, el3]).each(function(index, item){$(item).off('click')});
```

and then reassign the corresponding click event to the elements.

I think it should be a more elegant solution to this.

Another way I've found is to use this schema

```
$(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
    if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {
        alert('Clicked');
        e.handled = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method could be what you're looking for. I'd have left this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: one(): Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element. This isn't what I want. I need that if the handler is set for an element it won't be set again anymore or otherwise overwrite the existing handler. At the end, I don't want to have the same function executed twice on click for example.